# networkx matching with dtype=float64

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, networkx

I am trying to do matching using the networkx max weight matching function: 
http://networkx.lanl.gov/_modules/networkx/algorithms/matching.html

The matrix I am plugging in is dtype=float64 and I was wondering if networkx has support for that. I have the suspicion that the distances are affected by the rounding error and so the matching is not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Skimming through the source code it doesn't look like there should be any restriction to single precision, so float64 should work fine.